# LibGDX - HTML5 Run&Deploy

Tags: html, libgdx, tools.jar

I'm using Android Studio.
I want to run and deploy my application on HTML5.
I'm entering the command "**gradlew.bat html:superDev**" on the Terminal, but it gives me that error message:

**Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'. Could not find tools.jar**

How can I solve this problem?

Here's the full error message:

```
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:core:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.
> Could not find tools.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

1. You need install jdk [Download here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. You need configure your variable environment: JAVA_HOME

   Or you can copy tools.jar from %JAVA_HOME\lib to Android Studio\lib